# How to pass GDPR Consent to Flurry in android?

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics, gdprconsentform

I am trying to pass GDPR consent to flurry from my android app.
Per this documentation: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/android/gdpr/

I should use : 
 `consentStrings.put(“IAB”, iabString);`
but we don't use the IAB framework. What should be the key-value pair in that case?

Comment: looks like they allow consent for IAB only https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/gdpr/ what other scenario are you thinking you want to pass consent for?

Comment: I am also passing consent for CCPA through {setDataSaleOptOut} but since our app is available in EU as well, we need to make sure it is GDPR compliant.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, that method only supports IAB